# python user input using method and loops

Tags: python, mysql, function, user-input

'm trying to create employee database in MySql where the user has to select from userchoice. if the userchoice is 1, then it should go through insert method where the for loop has to run for 3 tries if the user gives incorrect data type in for loop. If he selects 2 it should go through delete where the user can select which field in the table to delete. Update is same as that of delete method. The userchoice should run until the user specifies it as e. The program should return an error if the user specifies wrong input. Editing the code would be preferred as I'm a newbie. Thanks for your help :)

```
class Emp():

    def create():

        abc= "CREATE TABLE tablename ( NAME CHAR(20), IDNO INT PRIMARY KEY, AGE INT,POSITION CHAR(20), SALARY INT)"
        cursor.execute(abc)

    def userchoice():
        print ("\n Enter 1 to insert datas")
        print ("\n Enter 2 to delete datas")
        print ("\n Enter 3 to update datas")
        print ("\n Enter e to exit")
        choices=input("Enter your choice:")

while choices !=e:

    def insert():
        if choices==1:
            try:
                tries=1
                n=int(raw_input("No of Empl:"))
                while tries<3:

                    for i in range(n):
                        name =raw_input("enter the name:")
                        mail_id =raw_input("enter the mail id:")
                        age =int(raw_input("enter the age:"))
                        salary =int(raw_input("enter salary:"))

                    print "Datas entered successfully"
                    cursor.execute(insert)
                    db.commit()
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print " max tries over"
                tries=tries+1

    def delete():
        if choices==2:
            print ("\n Enter 1 to delete name")
            print ("\n Enter 2 to delete position")
            print ("\n Enter 3 to delete age")
            print ("\n Enter 4 to delete salary")
            choe=input("Enter your choice:")
            try:
                if choe==1:
                    "ALTER TABLE tablename DROP 'name'";

                if choe==2:
                    "ALTER TABLE tablename DROP 'position'";

                if choe==3:
                    "ALTER TABLE tablename DROP 'age'";

                if choe==4:
                    "ALTER TABLE tablename DROP 'salary'";
                else:
                    print "select the correct choice to delete"
                cursor.execute(delete)
                db.commit()
            except ValueError:
                 print "enter crct i/p"

    def update():

        if choices==3:
            print ("\n Enter 1 to update name")
            print ("\n Enter 2 to update position")
            print ("\n Enter 3 to update age")
            print ("\n Enter 4 to update salary")

            cho=raw_input("Enter your choice:")

            if cho==1:
                "UPDATE employee_db SET Name = Name";

            if cho==2:
                "UPDATE employee_db SET Name";

            if cho==3:
                "UPDATE employee_db SET age = age + 5";

            if cho==4:
                "UPDATE employee_db SET SALARY = SALARY + 5000";
            else:
                print "enter the crct choice to update"

        if choices==4:
            print "bye"
while userchoice =='e':
    break
print "Please select the correct choice"

if __name__=='__main__':
    az=Emp()
    az.userchoice
    az.insert
    az.delete
    az.update
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you have `choices=input("Enter your choice:")` u cant declare a string `e`, use `raw_input()`. As the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) say, use raw_inputs for general input from users.

Second: the code has a wrong format. If you want the `while` in the class you should tab it in the `def userchoice()`.

Third: for this problem. Take out the `insert(), delete(), update()` implementations out of the while loop.

Fourth: In the `__main__` funtion you shouldn't be accessing the methods like an attribute. While accessing a method from a class you should add the `()` to the method name (and if necessary, pass the parameters).

Your code should look something like this:

```
class MyEmploye(object):
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        (...)
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        (...)
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        (...)
    def insert(self, *args, **kwargs):
        (...)
    def userchoice(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print ("\n Enter 1 to insert datas\n" + \
               " Enter 2 to...\n " + \
               " Enter 3 to.. \n" + \
               " Enter 4 to... \n")
        while choices != 'e':
            choices = raw_input("enter your choice: ")
            if choices == '1':
                self.insert()
            elif choices == '2':
                self.delete()
            elif choices == '3':
                self.update()
            elif choices == '4':
                self.create()

if __name__=='__main__':
    az=MyEmploye()
    az.userchoice()
```

Comment: My codes were working in python without def and mysql. when i use def and mysql codes, it produces no output

Comment: `raw_input()`is a python 2 function, which was renamed to `input()` in python 3. Since his print-statements use py3 syntax, the OP will most likely get an error using raw_input.

Comment: Also, your `while choices != 'e':` loop will execute the functions indefinitely, if something other than `e` is put in.

Comment: Can you explain or edit how my codes should look like?? I'm using python 2.7

Comment: @Christian and thats what the while loop should do, while the input isnt 'e' IT should loop. I ser the problem, the raw_input isnt in the loop, i'll Edit that

Comment: Also in py2.7 you Can print using "()", IT isnt a py3 only print statement.

Comment: I written the Basic od the code, i dont know od your code works as you want it to work. Just pastę you method implementations instead of the ``(...)``.

Comment: @DawidDaveKosiński - my comments weren't meant to be this harsh. Overall I liked the idea of your answer, so have my upvote. :)

Comment: i'm not offended, I just wasn't on the computer to copy all your code :)